# Overriding the CSS applied by "a" tag

Tags: css

I have below code,

```
<div id="nav">
   <a href="#" >Tab1</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab2</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab3</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab4</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab5</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab6</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab7</a>
   <a href="#" class="tab8Class">Tab8</a>
   <a href="#" >Tab9</a>
</div>

#nav a {
float: left;
color: #004761;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 9px 5px 9px 13px;
background-colour: white;
}

.tab8Class {
float: left;
color: #004761;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
padding: 9px 5px 9px 13px;
background-color: lightgray;
}
```

I want to apply a different `background-colour` for Tab8. So, for Tab8 alone I have added an extra class in the `a href` tag.

However, even for Tab8, `#nav a` is overriding all the attributes for `tab8Class`.

How can I make `tab8Class` to get applied?

Comment: missing !important.???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the second rules more specific (for more info take a look ,e.g., at [MDN on Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity)), so it does not get overridden by the first one. Additionally you don't have to repeat all unchanged properties:

```css
#nav a {
   float: left;
   color: #004761;
   font-size: 12px;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 9px 5px 9px 13px;
   background-color: white;
}

#nav .tab8Class {
   background-color: lightgray;
}
```

**[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGTUJ/)**

<sup>There was a typo in the first rule as well: It said `background-colour` instead of `background-color`.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Make your selector even more specific:

```css
#nav .tab8Class
```

You also remove the `u` in `colour` to have correct css:

```css
background-color: white;
              ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```css
#nav .tab8Class {
```

instead of:

```css
.tab8Class {
```

This will make your selector more **specific**.

You can read about CSS specificity [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/).

Answer (score 1):

Just change the bg color rule, no need to write all rules again.

```css
#nav a.tab8Class{

    background: #000 ; // change the color 

}
```

[specificity](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/&sa=U&ei=y8U5Ucy5G8nGmQWKroHgCA&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNHIpmrQvuRffDPoFcB4Gxr0sCck7w) you need to read something about this.

Comment: !important is not a good habit to get into, more specific tags are the way to go.

Comment: you should avoid !important at all costs IMO. .tab8Class is not as specific as #nav a so would not produce the required results. You need a higher specificity so #nav .tab8Class would be required.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1) remove the class and use:

```css
#nav a:nth-child(8){
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

2) this is more backward compatible:

```css
#nav .tab8Class{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

If you want to add a special hover effect (as assted in comments)

```css
#nav .tab8Class:hover{
     //Do something
}
```

Comment: If I want to put hovering affect specifically for `tab8Class`?

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below

```css
#nav a.tab8Class {
    float: left;
    color: #004761;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 9px 5px 9px 13px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply do it with jquery. Please add jquery library.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav a:eq(7)').addClass('tab8Class');
});
```

Comment: you should not resort to javascript to achieve something so trivial in CSS and markup